# Replace every nth character equal to "x"

Tags: javascript

I have a string where common characters are repeated.

For example

```
x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789
```

I'm trying to replace every nth occurrence of the character "x" starting from the first occurrence with the character "d" using javascript.

The final output should be as follows

```
d1234,x2345,d3456,x4567,d5678,x6789
```

Comment: Have you made any effort to write a JavaScript yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, I have tried several things that don't work. Hence, the necessity of posting a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function replaceNth(str, n, newChar) {
  const arr = str.split(',');
  return arr.map((item, i) => (i % n === 0) ? item.replace('x', newChar) : item).join(",")
}

const str = 'x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789';
// replace for every second string value
console.log(
  replaceNth(str, 2, 'd')
);
// replace for every third string value
console.log(
  replaceNth(str, 3, 'e')
);
```

Comment: Solved! Thank you!

Comment: Why split by comma?

Comment: Why not split on comma ? Seems OP is happy

Answer (score 2):

You could add a counter and replace by using a remainder for checking.

```js
function replace(string, char, repl, n) {
    var i = 0;
    return string.replace(new RegExp(char, 'g'), c => i++ % n ? c : repl);
}

console.log(replace('x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789', 'x', 'd', 2));
console.log(replace('x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789', 'x', 'd', 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var splittedWords = "x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789".split(",")
var result = splittedWords.map((element, index) => index % 2 ? element : "d" + element.substring(1))
console.log(result.join(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use a regular expression to match a pattern

```js
var str1 = "x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789"
var result1 = str1.replace( /x([^x]+(x|$))/g, 'd$1')
console.log(result1)

var str2 = "x1234,x2345,x3456"
var result2 = str2.replace( /x([^x]+(x|$))/g, 'd$1')
console.log(result2)
```

Explanation of reg exp: [RegExper](https://regexper.com/#%2Fx%28%5B%5Ex%5D%2B%28x%7C%24%29%29%2Fg)

or can just do a simple split, map, join

```js
var str = "x1234,x2345,x3456,x4567,x5678,x6789"
var result = str.split(",")  // split on comma
  .map((part,index) => // loop over array
    index % 2 === 0  // see if we are even or odd
      ? "d" + part.substring(1) // if even, remove first character, replace with 1
      : part)  // if odd, leave it
  .join(",")  // join it back together
console.log(result)
```

This assumes that the x is always after the comma, which may or may not be true. If not, then the logic needs to be more complicated.

Comment: I am not familiar with regex, if you don't mind expanding how does '$1' determine which character to replace.

Comment: basic concept of capture groups. Read documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @PeterB altered it